# How to disable the "autoland" when running "arc diff"?

Tags: diff, phabricator, arcanist

When I run `arc diff`, it asks `Autoland after builds pass and reviewers approve (Default Y)? [Y/n]`.

Can we change the setting to disable the autoland by default and avoid getting this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that there is a tag/flag for it. We can disable it by

> arc diff --noautoland